# iOS App shuts down when notification center and recently used app list are opened

Tags: ios, notificationcenter

My iOS app simply shuts down when I open notification center while the app is visible and in focus. Same thing happens if I double click the home button to show the recently used apps list.

This would seem to be an application lifecycle issue, but no errors are reported in Xcode.

How should I go about debugging this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by shuts down?  The application does move to an inactive state when the user opens notification center or double taps the home screen, that is normal behavior.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your 

`- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`

Comment: Is this a new project or are you working with a really old one (created before iOS4)? Could happen with an ancient tutorial project, legacy app sort of thing.

Comment: It's a really old project that is being updated (painfully). The `applicationWillResignActive:` function had an `exit(0)` call, causing the app to close. Issue is resolved. Thanks.